# One modifier for a group of objects

Tags: modifiers, workflow, groups, collections

I know blender is really weak when it comes to this sort of thing compared to other 3D software. But is there ANY way of using a modifier on more than one object? This would be especially useful for the Array modifier.
Things I've thought of that don't work:
- Use parenting
- Use collections
- Use a boolean modifier (This almost works if only there was an option to only "join" them without changing the meshes)

As a practical example, I'm building some pipes that are screwed together. I would like to somehow still be able to change details (thickness and number of the screws, bevels ...) by just changing it in one place. In Cinema4D this would have taken a few minutes, but in Blender it seems almost impossible.
For now, I'm just using copies of the same array modifier on every single element. This doesn't really scale.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This older thread could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/319/78972

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a modifier to a collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159806/how-to-add-a-modifier-to-a-collection)