# Modifiers vanish during copy operation - why?

Tags: modifiers

Blender 4.0.2: I follow the advice in [How to add a modifier to a collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159806/how-to-add-a-modifier-to-a-collection) to copy modifiers, but Blender does not behave the way I expected it to:

For one element in a collection, I create a modifier "Mod 1":

[image]

Then I try to copy it. I first select the other object, then the one with the modifier "Mod 1".

[image]

Then I press Ctrl+L and select "copy modifiers". The modifiers vanish. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

The modifier has 0 connections

[image]

Comment: The answer in the link unfortunately does not mention that the objects are selected in the _3D Viewport_, not the _Outliner_. For an explanation see the answer below by @MartynasŽiemys. As a general rule remember the following: usually the **active object** is the one which taken into account when copying materials, modifiers, joining objects etc. No matter how you selected, to make sure the correct object is active you can check things like: the active object has a brighter outline than other selected ones. And the top left of the viewport shows the name of the active object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy modifiers operator like many other operators in Blender works by taking data from the active object and then performing the operation to all selected objects.

If you select one object in the outliner and then another using  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  clicking, the active object remains the same, so it remains the first object selected, which in your case is the one that has no modifiers. If you then copy modifiers, the absence of modifiers is copied over from the active object to any selected objects. If you want to select and make the last selected object active in the outliner, you would have to  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   click it when selecting it or when it's already selected any other way. If you select your objects in 3d viewport, the last selected will become active in normal circumstances so it will act as you expect if you select your objects in the 3d viewport.

Note that active object is also not changed in 3d viewport when selecting in certain ways. For example if you select one object and then  <kbd>Shift</kbd>   drag select others.